# Droplist Using ENUM, Populate Value That The User Holds and Show The Remaining Value Inside Option

Tags: php, enums

Basically, it would be lovely to only use PHP for now as I have a little knowledge regarding JavaScript at the moment.

Okay, here's the idea. Instead of talking nonsense I will provide image instead.

1. The initial value each user hold.
   [image]
2. The imaginary drop-list that I made just to show that this is what I wanted it to looks like
   [image]
3. But, if the value is 'PAID' then it will show both the same, which I wanted the other value to be the opposite of the current selected value (in this case the 'PAID' value)
   [image]
   Here's the code (please go easy on me, I know it is messed up)

```html
while( $rowresult = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ) )
{
  $idtosave[] = $rowresult['id'];
     
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$rowresult['id']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$rowresult['username']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$rowresult['useric']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$rowresult['userphone']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$rowresult['useremail']."</td>";
  echo "<form method=post>";
  echo "<td><select name='changepay[]'>";
  echo "<option value='".$rowresult['pay']."'>".$rowresult['pay']."</option>";
  echo "<option value='PAID'>PAID</td>"; // the imaginary drop-list...
  echo "</select>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Just for another round of understanding, person A held value (NONE) so on his drop-list will show the remaining value (PAID), person B held value (PAID) so on his drop-list will show the remaining value (NONE), and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'ternary operator' will compare the data from the table. If the data is equal to 'PAID' then it will make 'PAID' option as selected while if not equal to 'PAID'. Then, it will show the remaining option as it's first selected value which is the 'NONE'.

```
while( $rowresult = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ) )
            {
                $idtosave[] = $rowresult['id'];
                $selected = $rowresult['pay'] == 'PAID' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$rowresult['id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$rowresult['username']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$rowresult['useric']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$rowresult['userphone']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$rowresult['useremail']."</td>";
                echo "<form method=post>";
                echo "<td><select name='changepay[]'>";
                echo "<option value='NONE' >NONE</option>";
                echo "<option value='PAID' $selected>PAID</option>";
                echo "</select></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
```